# How to select a row that has been clicked

Tags: javascript, css

I want have a list of items in which the color of a selected element turns red when it is selected and all of the other divs turn blue. How can I identify the selected div that would then turn red?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table_1 .tableRow div').click(function(event) {

    //Set the style for all divs
    var myElements = document.querySelectorAll("#table_1 .tableRow div");
    for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
      myElements[i].className = "blueText";
    }
    //Set the style for tyhe selected div
    //selectedItem.className="selectedText";
  });
});
```

```css
.selectedText {
  color: red;
}
.blueText {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="table_1" class="table">
    <div class="tableRow">
      <div>
        Line 1
      </div>
      <div>
        Line 2
      </div>
      <div>
        Line 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 'this' refers to the current clicked element. Hence, after the 'for' loop, add -- $(this).removeClass('blueText'); $(this).addClass('selectedText');

Comment: You may want to include jquery as a tag on your post. Since you're using jquery, there may be an easy jquery way of doing what you want. Edit: j08691's answer is exactly what I was talking about.

Comment: @Nitin Thanks, I did not know I needed to remove the existing class before adding the new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's enough to change:

```
//selectedItem.className="selectedText";
```

to:

```
event.target.className="selectedText";
```

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#table_1 .tableRow div').click(function(event) {

    //Set the style for all divs
    var myElements = document.querySelectorAll("#table_1 .tableRow div");
    for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
      myElements[i].className="blueText";
    }
    //Set the style for tyhe selected div
    event.target.className="selectedText";
  });
});
```

```css
.selectedText {
  color: red;
}
.blueText {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div  id="table_1" class="table">
    <div class="tableRow">
        <div>
            Line 1
        </div>
        <div >
            Line 2
        </div>
        <div >
            Line 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with this:

```js
$('#table_1 .tableRow div').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass().addClass('selectedText').siblings().removeClass().addClass('blueText')
})
```

```css
.selectedText {
  color: red;
}
.blueText {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table_1" class="table">
  <div class="tableRow">
    <div>
      Line 1
    </div>
    <div>
      Line 2
    </div>
    <div>
      Line 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pure CSS solution using [**tabindex**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp) and [**:focus**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp) Selector for DIV's.

```css
div:focus {
    color: red;
}

div {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div  id="table_1" class="table">
    <div class="tableRow">
        <div tabindex="1">Line 1</div>

        <div tabindex="2">Line 2</div>

        <div tabindex="3">Line 3</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$(this)` object to reference the element on which a jQuery handler was made:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        $('#table_1 .tableRow div').click(function(event) {

            //Set the style for all divs
            var myElements = document.querySelectorAll("#table_1 .tableRow div");
            for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {   
                myElements[i].className="blueText";
            }

            $(this).addClass('selectedText')
        });
    });
```

Also, if you want to use something other than just the CSS class to determine if an element is selected or not (outside of the jQuery callback), you could add a `data-*` attribute to it [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Comment: Also, just for clarity, I would recommend moving the block of code after the comment "Set the style for all divs" to a separate method, so you can call this method.